# How I could write it better? Without Counter etc. libraries

Tags: python, arrays, counter

Hello I'm learning Python and I've a question for you. My script count how many times numbers 0-9 found in the the array and save data in format [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0].....]. ? How I could write it better without any libraries? I would like expand the horizons of Python knowledge and improve my own skills.

My code:

```
inp=input("Enter a sequence of numbers: ")
tab=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    counter=0
    for c in inp:
        if c == str(i):
            counter+=1
    tab.append([])
    tab[i].append(i)
    tab[i].append(counter)
print(tab)
```

Example Input

```
Enter a sequence of numbers: 111112222333445
```

Output

```
[[0, 0], [1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0]]
```

Best regards

Comment: I don't see any libraries being used here...

Comment: Its true. But i would like see other solutions of this problem, much better than my

Comment: Working code that you would like to optimize should be posted on CodeReview instead of StackOverflow

Comment: @cricket_007 yes looks good for codereview

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, that is the point, to do it without using a library

Answer (score 2):

### Nice to read

```
inp = '111112222333445'
numbers = [int(number) for number in inp]
res = [[index, 0] for index in range(10)] 
for number in numbers:
    res[number][-1] += 1
print(res)

[[0, 0], [1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0]]
```

### Convert to `int` in the loop

```
inp = '111112222333445'
res = [[index, 0] for index in range(10)] 
for number in inp:
    res[int(number)][-1] += 1
```

### Using `map`

```
inp = '111112222333445'
res = [[index, 0] for index in range(10)] 
for number in map(int, numbers):
    res[number][-1] += 1
```

Comment: Line 2 could also be `map(int, inp)`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. There are more variations.

Comment: @Rarez Did you find any of these useful?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just create your own Counter dict to do the counting using a regular dict:

```
inp = "111112222333445"

d = {}.fromkeys(range(10), 0)
for i in map(int, inp):
    d[i] += 1

print([[i, d[i]] for i in range(10)])
[[0, 0], [1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0]]
```

if the order  does not necessarily matter and you are ok with tuples just call `list(d.items())`:

```
print(list(d.items()))
```

Answer (score -1):

the simples way is to use the class `Counter` in the module collections, a `Counter` is a `dict` that store how many time a certain item is in the list or iterable given to it.

That is something like this:

```
from collection import Counter 
inp=input("Enter a sequence of numbers: ") #str
cuenta = Counter(inp) #{char:int}
print(list(cuenta.items())) #[ (char,int) ] , items() give the contents of a dict in 
                            #tuples of the form (key,value)
```

with `Counter(inp)` you're treating `inp` like a list of char, you can also use `filter` to remove the no digit char in `inp` like this

```
filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),inp)
```

then changing `cuenta` for

```
cuenta = Counter(filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),inp))
```

**But if you don't want to use** `Counter` or `filter` because the functional programming style is still to unfamiliar to you, then instead of using a list, I would rather use a `dict` and code the work that Counter do for me like this:

```
inp=input("Enter a sequence of numbers: ") #str
digit_count = dict( [ (n,0) for n in range(10) ] ) #inicialize this dict with the keys 
                                                   #that I care about and a value of zero, 
                                                   #meaning that a see none of them yet
for char in inp:          #here I treat inp like a list of char
    if char.isdigit() :   #I make sure that is a number
        digit_count[ int(char) ] += 1 
tab = list(digit_count.items())  
print( tab )
```

if you really need that `tab` be a list of list, then you can do it like this

```
tab = list( list(elem) for elem in digit_count.items() )
```

Furthermore you can build a generic counter function like this

```
def counter(iterable)
    """Function that return a list of the form [(item,count)] where
       item are the elements of iterable and count is how many times
       is present in there"""
    counter = dict()
    for elem in iterable:
        if elem in counter:
            counter[elem] += 1
        else:
            counter[elem] = 1
    return list(counter.items()) #or just return the counter
```

doing this you can reuse this code in other situations where it may be needed instead of have to write it again, after all modurability and re-usability are the mark of a good programmer